# Inport Text file as Value

Tags: vb.net

I'm wanting to make a small VB.net program that auto fills in form data and creates Accounts. I'm currently stuck with what I should do because i want to set the value of create email from a Text file. Here is my code as of now...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create-email").SetAttribute("value", "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create-password").SetAttribute("value", "PASSWORD")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create-submit").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        WebBrowser1.Size = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Size
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

I would like Button 2 click to be the value of ID: create-email. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, you said "i want to set the value of create email from a Text file" and "I would like Button 2 click to be the value of ID: create-email. How can I do this?"

So which one is it, or is it both?

You create a variable outside the method, like:

```
Private DataHolder as String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create-email").SetAttribute("value", DataHolder)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create-password").SetAttribute("value", "PASSWORD")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create-submit").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
       DataHolder = File.ReadLines("something") 'read you text file here
End Sub
```

Comment: Both. Basically when Button 2 is pressed, it opens up a dialog box... allows you to open the text documents with lists of emails.... Those emails are then placed 1 by 1 in the set attributes. Then when the form is submitted; it reads the next email address below the first email.... and So forth.

Comment: And how is this list formatted? What does separate one email from another?

Comment: Not Sure. after hours of figuring it out. I have openfilediaglog working and the create email read the file from openfiledialog. My only problem now is making the data read 1 by 1 and not as all 1 as text.

Comment: What do you mean you are not sure, if you have a list of emails have a look at it, is it like "email1, email2...." or "email+email2..." or something else.

Comment: In the Text document, it is simply Line 1 XXXX@gmail.com and then on line 2, XXXX2@gmail.com

Comment: So it simply a string split by a newchar, ok. Now you didn't specify how you need it but you can do it the following way. Create a new list of string, readall on file, string split by newline and .tolist it, and done.